# How to create a Toolbar for IE?

Tags: toolbar

i need to create a toolbar for IE. And i have the code for to develop that for Firefox.
but i dont have the link for the IE tutorial for Toolbar development.
if any one know please reply me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ sample: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/ietoolbartutorial.aspx)

VB sample: [link](http://www.klemid.de/bar_sample.aspx)

Comment: any other links, i tried some other tutorials too, but didn't any solution... is there any tutorial avaiable

Answer (score 2):

[BestToolbars](http://www.besttoolbars.net) gives you a fully extensible platfrom for creating IE toolbars. Their platform is capable of running JAvascripts so that you can actually use Javascript to create the functionality and not to mess up with C++ or VB.